# nginx caching: return cached page (when specific Cache-Control header given) only if the upstream server is not reachable

Tags: nginx, caching

I'm trying to set up caching for an upstream server (which I do not manage). Most files can be cached (and don't have `Cache-Control` set), those work fine.

**However, some locations on the server are directory listings (and have `Cache-Control: no-store`). I'd like to cache those only if the server is not reachable.**
Unfortunately, I either end up in one of the following:

- In a situation where those listings are not cached (no file in the cache, header always shows a cache miss). If the server is not reachable, the directory listings are (obviously) not returned
- In a situation where those listings are cached, but they never update afterwards (at least not as long as the cache is valid). Since I'd like to cache all of the other entries for a long time, the directory listings become outdated quickly.

I tried to modify the headers to `stale-if-error`, but that didn't seem to help either.

```
map $http_cache_control $http_updated_cache_control {
  no-store stale-if-error;
}

server {
...
  location /somewhere {
      sendfile on;
      sendfile_max_chunk 10m;
      tcp_nopush on;
      proxy_cache keyzone;

      # allow using stale requests in case of errors or when updating a file
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_revalidate on;
      proxy_cache_background_update on;

      # add header to indicate if caching works
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

      proxy_cache_lock on;
      proxy_read_timeout  900;
      proxy_pass_header   Server;
      proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;

      # allow caching of non-cacheable entries only when the server is erroring
      proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
      add_header Cache-Control $http_updated_cache_control;

      # don't ignore the cache control header: some items (like directory listings) are marked as "don't cache")
      #proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
  }
}
```

How can I cache entries with `Cache-Control: no-store`, but only use the cached entries if the upstream server is down?

Comment: Add response headers of both the upstream server, and your proxy. What do you mean by "(at least not as long as the cache is valid)"? How the validity of the cache is defined for `Cache-Control: no-store` content?

Comment: I meant: if I set proxy_cache_valid to a large value (ideally a few days), the things I want to cache are cached for a long time.
Unfortunately, that means the items I only want to cache in case of error, are also cached (and used) for 10 days.
If I put it to a very short value, then the items I want to cache are not cached long either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. NGINX respects headers from the upstream server. So if the upstream sends `Expires` despite the `Cache-Control: no-store` then after you modify headers for NGINX they become `Expires: ... Cache-Control: stale-if-error` and it waits

   > at least as long as the cache is valid
2. `proxy_cache_valid` probably have the same effect

So you need to

1. either set some small value for `proxy_cache_valid` for `location /somewhere`
2. or/and remove `Expires` if it's present
3. or/and add `max-age=0` to `Cache-Control`

Comment: Thanks! I've configured a small value (10 seconds) for proxy_cache_valid now. Since I've set proxy_cache_use_stale to return while 'updating', this means I get a stale response at least once (for example if I do 1 request, wait an hour and do a second, the second one will be very old).
However, if I leave out 'updating', it means it will revalidate, so I made that small change as well. Now it behaves as it should! Thanks! :-)